# Can you make alias for another variable in scala?

Tags: scala, variables, alias, function

Is it possible to make an alias for item of an array in scala? The code below won't work but something like that.

```
var str=new ArrayBuffer[String](10)
def alias = str(1)
alias="test"
print(alias)
```

The code below works and basically what I want to do with the code above. But I don't want to type str(ALIAS) everytime I use this variable. I want shorter name

```
var str=new ArrayBuffer[String](10)
val ALIAS=1
str(ALIAS) = "test"
print(str(ALIAS))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a standard setter syntax:

```
var str= Array("a", "b", "c")

def alias = str(1)
def alias_=(s: String) {
  str(1) = s
}

alias = "test"
print(alias)
```

Comment: I run that code exactly and get: `scala> alias = "test"
<console>:9: error: value alias_= is not a member of object $iw
       alias = "test"
       ^`

Comment: @nicerobot: for some reason it doesn't work in REPL, but works fine when compiled.